# Kiwi test target using Cocoapods

Tags: ios, unit-testing, cocoapods, kiwi

I've added Kiwi via Cocoapods. This is the content of the podfile

```
platform :ios, '5.0'

pod 'BlocksKit'
pod 'ViewUtils'
pod 'AwesomeMenu'

target :KiwiUnitTest, :exclusive => true do
      pod 'Kiwi'
end
```

I can run the app without problems. But if I hit cmd+u to run the test target (KiwiUnitTest) I get some errors. 
A class (ParticleView) that should be tested uses BlocksKit (included via Cocoapods). So I added ParticleView to the test target (KiwiUnitTest) and the error says "No visible interface for ... declares the selector ... 
It seems like that the test target don't know anything about the Cocoapods.

I've already added `$(inherited)` to the `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS` and added `$(BUNDLE_LOADER)` to the Test Host. Remove `:exclusive =>` true from the podfile did not help

I deleted everything and setup the whole cocoapods and test target from the scratch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove the `:exclusive` and add the same imports from the main target `.pch` file to the kiwi unit test `.pch` file solved the problem

```
platform :ios, '5.0'

pod 'BlocksKit'
pod 'ViewUtils'
pod 'AwesomeMenu'

target :KiwiUnitTest do
      pod 'Kiwi'
end
```